# How can I remove special characters from a list of elements in python?

Tags: python, string, list, special-characters

I have a list of elements containing special characters.  I want to convert the list to only alphanumeric characters.  No special characters.
my_list = ["on@3", "two#", "thre%e"]

my expected output is,

```
out_list = ["one","two","three"]
```

I cannot simply apply `strip()` to these items, please help.

Comment: write a function that will remove the special characters from one string, then use `map` or a list comprehension to apply that function to the list of strings.

Comment: Where did the `3` in `on@3` go? Are you also replacing digits with letters?

Comment: You have underspecified as well. What about other punctuation? What about whitespace? One of the answers below preserves only letters and digits for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`str.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)  to apply the same translation table to all strings:

```
removetable = str.maketrans('', '', '@#%')
out_list = [s.translate(removetable) for s in my_list]
```

The [`str.maketrans()` static method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) is a helpful tool to produce the translation map; the first two arguments are empty strings because you are not replacing characters, only removing. The third string holds all characters you want to remove.

Demo:

```
>>> my_list = ["on@3", "two#", "thre%e"]
>>> removetable = str.maketrans('', '', '@#%')
>>> [s.translate(removetable) for s in my_list]
['on3', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: The first string in the list has `3` replaced by `e`.

Comment: @roganjosh: *or* there is an error in the expected input or output. I've asked for clarification on the question. Note that none of the other answers address this too.

Comment: Indeed you did, sorry. I jumped from question to your answer and then followed up your link, without seeing your comments under the question.

Answer (score 15):

Here is another solution:

```
import re
my_list= ["on@3", "two#", "thre%e"]
print [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', _) for _ in my_list]
```

**output:**

```
['on3', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
l_in = ["on@3", "two#", "thre%e"]
l_out = [''.join(e for e in string if e.isalnum()) for string in l_in]
print l_out
>['on3', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using two for loops

```
l = ['@','#','%']
out_list = []
for x in my_list:
    for y in l:
        if y in x:
            x = x.replace(y,'')
            out_list.append(x)
            break
```

Using list comprehension

```
out_list = [ x.replace(y,'')  for x in my_list for y in l if y in x ]
```

Assuming `3` in `on@3` is a typo, the output will be `on@3` and not `one` as expected

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but this looping will take more time ]

Comment: @pyd: you'd have to loop for stripping too.

Comment: On the other hand, the *double loop* here is rather overkill.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks! if I'm to use list comprehension doesn't that also have the same issue?

Comment: A list comprehension doesn’t alter the number of loops, no. All it does is make list building more efficient. What you need is a method to replace all characters with a single command, like `str.translate()`, at which point you have a single loop rather than a double.