# How to remove unwanted characters from list of string?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I want to remove the special characters using `re` library
and by using only one method: cleanName(),
I am coding on code chef

```
input_list=["Donald_Trump", "Joe1@Bidden", "Kamala Harris1"]

output_list=["Donald Trump", "Joe Bidden", "Kamala Harris"]
```

I am using this code but didn't get help:

```
import re
input_list=["Donald_Trump", "Joe1@Bidden", "Kamala Harris1"]
print [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', _) for _ in input_list]

can it be done through iteration(using for loop)?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removing special characters from a list of items in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301795/removing-special-characters-from-a-list-of-items-in-python)

Comment: sorry but noooooooo

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have 2 cases here.

1. Replace some characters with a space
2. Replace some characters with nothing

```
import re

input_list=["Donald_Trump", "Joe1@Bidden", "Kamala Harris1"]

output_list=[re.sub(r"[_@]", " ", word) for word in input_list]
output_list=[re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z\s]", "", word) for word in output_list]

print(output_list) # ['Donald Trump', 'Joe Bidden', 'Kamala Harris']
```

As requested, in a for loop:

```
import re

input_list = ["Donald_Trump", "Joe1@Bidden", "Kamala Harris1"]

output_list = []

for word in input_list:
  filtered_word = re.sub(r"[_@]", " ", word)
  filtered_word = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z\s]", "", filtered_word)

  output_list.append(filtered_word)

print(output_list)
```

Comment: it is working but can we do this with the help of for loop.

Comment: @annypanny I've added a version with a for loop.

Comment: You're welcome. If it is the right answer for you, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your print should have a bracket in python 3.0+ and instead of `''`, change to `' '` or `""`.
The differences between a single quote(`''`) and double quote(`""`) are double quote has 1 length in it and the single quote has 0. Try assigning both of them into a variable and use the `len()` to find out.

`print([re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', ' ', _) for _ in input_list])`

Comment: unexpected output: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x2b34fe0a80f8>

Comment: @annypanny Edited version should work now. I missed out the `[` on the previous code.